# Trying to convert inconsistently formatted price strings to cents

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm migrating data over from one database to another, and am writing the appropriate scripts. I want to start on a clean slate and fix a lot of the inconsistent formatting allowed by the previous app, specifically with prices, the following all being examples of prices currently stored in the previous database:

```
-100.00
700.00
0.01
3,200.00
3200
1,750.5
0
500/hour
```

I would like to convert everything into cents, so the above would be:

```
-10000
70000
1
320000
320000
175050
0
50000
```

I was hopeful when FORMAT(price, 2) * 100 seemed to work on a lot of them, including (!) 500/hour:

```
select format('500/hour', 2) * 100;
-> 50000
```

But for some reason, I'm getting weird results for 3200.00:

```
select format('3200.00', 2) * 100;
-> 300
```

While writing this, It appears that it doesn't work for any numeric strings above 1,000, and I'm guessing it has something to do with the presence/lack of a comma. Is there any intelligent way to parse the above examples into cents? If it is simple enough, I'd love to just incorporate it into the select query, but a user defined function is also fine.

Comment: The reason is that `format()` adds commas to numbers over 1000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first remove the comma with this sentence:

```
replace(data,',','')
```

This could be because you have a varchar type instead of an int type. If you do

```
select cast(replace('3,200.00',',','') as signed) * 100
```

It should work

Comment: @ Michael O. I just modified

Comment: You don't need the `cast`. MySQL will automatically convert strings to numbers when used in an arithmetic operation.

Comment: Awesome. Just wanted to echo @Barmar that cast is not needed. In fact, casting to an integer stripped away any floating points, so 450.5 would turn into 45000, whereas leaving CAST() out resulted in the correct output.